# Exporting OBJ mesh in blender

Tags: mesh

I am trying to export a simple shape: torus, sphere. the exported mesh is in OBJ format. Blender displays an error "location is unknown or something related to volume. If I increase the scale to 100 ( setting of OBJ export) still the error displayed. Do you have any idea why I cannot get the OBJ mesh?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Volumes/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/__init__.py", line 311, in execute
        return export_obj.save(context, **keywords)
    File "/Volumes/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py", line 791, in save
        EXPORT_PATH_MODE=path_mode,
    File "/Volumes/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py", line 733, in _write
        progress,
    File "/Volumes/Blender/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.80/scripts/addons/io_scene_obj/export_obj.py", line 389, in write_file
        bpy.data.meshes.remove(me)
    RuntimeError: Error: Mesh 'sphere' is outside of main database and can not be removed from it
```

The link to the files:

The STL mesh: https://gofile.io/?c=iycaiS

Blender file:https://gofile.io/?c=yLi0Pp

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full error message.

Comment: I am attaching the error, I couldnot screen shot since the message disappear, so I attached as video.

Answer (score 1):

This issue appears when you're trying to export an object that contains no geometry, because of a single erroneous line in `export_obj.py`. This bug has already been reported and fixed in [D5479](https://developer.blender.org/D5479) by Philipp Oeser. The fixed version of the exporter will be available in Blender 2.81.

In your case the object 'sphere' contains no geometry, which triggers this error. As a workaround until 2.81 is released you can either just select objects that contain geometry and enable *Selection Only* in the exporter or you could simply delete the problematic object. Alternatively you could also change the one line of code in the obj exporter yourself.

Comment: I am not sure, I do understand this answer. Actually I have tried different shapes, see the question I am adding more screen shot

Comment: It's not about which shapes you've tried. There is an object named 'sphere' in your scene which contains no geometry and when you try to export the entire scene it causes the issue that you're describing. Delete the 'sphere' object (and all other objects that contain no geometry) and it will work properly.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I am trying to export the twisted yarn as in the description and it fails. I used spheres and other shapes to test. The question is how to make sure. that the object contains geometry? or any example would be appreciated.

Comment: You can go through the objects in the outliner one by one and for each object switch into the edit mode. If there are no vertices, face or edges then it doesn't contain geometry. Perhaps you can upload your project and link it to your question so we can take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: For this mesh, it has vertice, faces, and edges, that's why I don't understand, why it doesn't export in OBJ format. I am attaching the links in the description.

Comment: The STL mesh: https://gofile.io/?c=iycaiS

Blender file:https://gofile.io/?c=yLi0Pp

Comment: @Monika The .blend project you've linked is ok and exports fine using the official release of Blender 2.80. Do you see the same error message as before when trying to export it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99659/discussion-between-rjg-and-monika).